# Image shows darker when i view it through the browser, still shows well on my laptop

Tags: image, rendering, photoshop, jpeg

When i try to load a website it shows like this on my desktop:

http://img846.imageshack.us/img846/9646/1354627721863.jpg

Now normally it should flow well like it shows on my laptop:

http://unforgivenwow.com/theknight/unforgivenwow/

anybody a clue?

Nvm, got it fixed. Appearantly windows used my monitor his colors so i changed those to rgba.

Answer (score 0):

Different monitors display images differently. If it's just a matter of the image color quality, your monitor might not be able to handle all of the colors. If it's a matter of speed, then it's probably an issue with your computer or internet connection.